# Help clarifying fraction and percentage question.

Tags: fractions, percentages

I have the following problem:

> Convert the mixed number $18 \frac 25 \%$ to an improper fraction, then, use the definition of percent to convert to fractional notation.

If I follow the steps of the question I will first convert to an improper fraction $\frac {92}5 \%$. Here is where I get lost. Is the question really saying to multiply this by $100$ (the definition of percent)? Or is it saying convert that to a straight percentage? So would I be showing this answer as $\frac{92/5}{100}$, or is it $\frac{92\cdot 100}{5\cdot 100}$?
The answer the program is telling me I should arrive at is $\frac{23}{125}$.

Comment: $92/5 \% = 92/5 \cdot 1/100$, then simplify.

Comment: Thank you david. I edited the question just before your answer with the solution the program tells me I should arrive at and I'm just completely at a loss.

Comment: Nevermind, I see my error. Thank you!

Comment: Notice that $4$ divides evenly into both $92$ and $100$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were correct with $\frac{\frac {92}5}{100}=\frac {92}{500}=\frac {23}{125}$ where the last step is dividing top and bottom by $4$